# Sample Code for metadata-extractor is generating "NoClassDefFoundError"

Tags: java, metadata, jpeg, noclassdeffounderror, metadata-extractor

I am trying to extract the latitude and longitude from picture files in my java app. I am using intellij for my IDE. I found this library that looks perfect: https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/2.14.0/jar
I tried the sample code found at
https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/blob/master/Samples/com/drew/metadata/SampleUsage.java

I copied the jar to my project directory and then added it as a directory.
I copied and pasted the sample code to a class.

I immediately got errors that the class "Metadata" was not recognized so I added an import line for com.drew.metadata.* and that got rid of those errors.

Now when I try to run the code I get a series of errors of NoClassDefFoundError and am stuck.

Code up to the last line that is throwing the errors:

```
import com.drew.imaging.ImageMetadataReader;
import com.drew.imaging.ImageProcessingException;
import com.drew.imaging.jpeg.JpegMetadataReader;
import com.drew.imaging.jpeg.JpegProcessingException;
import com.drew.imaging.jpeg.JpegSegmentMetadataReader;
import com.drew.metadata.exif.ExifReader;
import com.drew.metadata.iptc.IptcReader;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

// fran added this one
import com.drew.metadata.*;


public class ExtractLatLng {
    public static void extract()
    {
        String fileAndPath = "C:/Users/Franc/Documents/$$Fran/misc/_online Ed/Picture Renaming/PhotoRenaming0903/IMG_5408.jpg";
        File file = new File(fileAndPath);

        // There are multiple ways to get a Metadata object for a file

        //
        // SCENARIO 1: UNKNOWN FILE TYPE
        //
        // This is the most generic approach.  It will transparently determine the file type and invoke the appropriate
        // readers.  In most cases, this is the most appropriate usage.  This will handle JPEG, TIFF, GIF, BMP and RAW
        // (CRW/CR2/NEF/RW2/ORF) files and extract whatever metadata is available and understood.
        //
        try {
            Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(file);
```

Errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/adobe/internal/xmp/XMPException
at com.drew.imaging.jpeg.JpegMetadataReader.<clinit>(JpegMetadataReader.java:57)
at com.drew.imaging.ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(ImageMetadataReader.java:146)
at com.drew.imaging.ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(ImageMetadataReader.java:124)
at com.drew.imaging.ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(ImageMetadataReader.java:204)
at PR0903.ExtractLatLng.extract(ExtractLatLng.java:35)
at PR0903.Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

P.S. I am a total newbie. Any help appreciated including better ways/places to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it out. Apparently I needed to include and xmpcore library as well that was not available or included in the metadata-extractor download site. I searched around and found one to download. Included it as a library in my project and it works now.

Comment: Yep, that's the reason. Note that if you use Maven then package dependencies are downloaded automatically.